# Apache 2.2.3 reverse proxy issue

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have to setup a website **https://xyz.abc.co.in** using self-signed certificate. I have apache 2.2.3 on Redhat Linux. But the home page of that website should come from a remote server application i.e http://10.x1.x2.x3:7080/app working on glassfish.
When i write http://10.x1.x2.x3:7080/app in browser it opens http://10.x1.x2.x3:7080/app_web/login.html
Now on my Apache 2.2.3 i have following entry in my httpd.conf to call http://10.x1.x2.x3:7080/app through remote proxy :-

```
< VirtualHost * :443  >  
    ServerName xyz.abc.co.in  
    SSLEngine On  
    SSLProxyEngine On  
    ProxyRequests Off  
    ProxyPreserveHost On  
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/*/redhat.crt  
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/*/redhat1.key  
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html  
    ProxyPass / http://10.x1.x2.x3:7080/app/  
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.x1.x2.x3:7080/app/  
<  /VirtualHost>
```

Now when i use https://xyz.abc.co.in in browser it gives error "NO DATA RECIEVED".
I have loaded module proxy_html also.
When i remove directive "SetOutputFilter proxy-html" then it gives error that :-
/app_web/login.html is not found on port 80 of apache 2.2.3 ( although it is hosted on glassfish on remote server).  When I use "ProxyHTMLInterp On" then also there are the same errors recieved in browser.
....When i use "ProxyHTMLEnable On" it says invalid command while starting apache.
Please suggest.